# Dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my pre-installed windows 8 Lenovo G580. But after installing Ubuntu, it's Grub doesn't show windows8 in it. Can any one help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try Boot-Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

A simple tool to repair frequent boot issues.